# Why did my sheep spawn pink?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While I was building a barn for sheep, I spawned a lot -- and I mean a *lot* -- of sheep. Then I noticed something funny: I spawned a *pink* sheep. I didn't have any dye in my inventory. How on earth did this happen? Could someone please explain?

Comment: Next time, just for lols, try posting a picture to really show us how much a lot is. It also helps to post pictures when asking questions

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Pink sheep can spawn naturally without dye, very rarely:

> Pink sheep have a 0.164% of naturally spawning

Sheep can spawn naturally in white, black, grey, light grey, brown and pink with the following chances of spawning:

- White - 81.836%
- Black - 5%
- Grey - 5%
- Light Grey - 5%
- Brown - 3%
- Pink - 0.164%

Sheep will *never* naturally spawn in any other colour than listed above.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sheep)

Comment: But they can be changed to other colours such as Blue and pass those colours on via breeding

Comment: @Robotnik Breeding does not count as spawning naturally since they have to be interacted with in order to breed.

Comment: @Pharap - of course not, I was just pointing it out :)

Comment: Good answer. Do you happen to know why Pink is 0.164%? 41/25000 seems like a really odd probability. (Also, I'm sorry for downvoting the accepted answer and pushing you further from your Populist badge :P)

Comment: @Schism 0.164% is about 1/610 - not quite as odd as 41/25000.  The probabilities make a fair amount of sense if the underlying probabilities are [500, 30, 30, 30, 20, 1].  (If that's the case, though, then the probability for white is a little off due to giving it all the rounding error.)

Answer (score 11):

By spawning, I assume you mean either breeding or spawning in creative. Both of these have a chance to spawn a pink sheep, although its quite rare. You may notice that they're spawning other colors too, like green or blue. If you want to get them back to their original white color, right click on them with bonemeal.

EDIT: As someone pointed out in the comments, it is not possible to obtain a pink sheep by random breeding. Only by breeding red with white, or pink with red or white can you obtain pink sheep by breeding.

Comment: I actually got a screen shot on my home computer of a pink sheep but i could never get a second one so i wasn't sure of the cause and it was a few versions ago so i assumed it was apart of the natural color selection for sheep spawning but "unnatrual" colors like pink, blue, magenta i assume have an insanely high random chance over black, white and brown that it's almost impossible

Comment: That is incorrect. Sheep will never spawn green or blue, or any colours other than pink, white, black, light grey, grey, brown and pink.

Comment: Also incorrect in that **breeding** sheep will never have a **chance** of getting a pink sheep **randomly**. You can only get a pink sheep if you breed a pink sheep with another sheep or a red sheep with a white sheep (which doesn't seem like what OP did)

Comment: i didnt  breed they spawned in creative

Comment: By the way i spawned it with an egg